# show that $1)$ $f$ has removable singularity at $\infty$ if $n \ge m$ $2)$ $Res [f(z) : \infty]=0 $ if $n \ge m +2$

Tags: complex-analysis

let $p(z)$ and $q(z)$  be  polynomial  with  no common zeros , and with  degree $m$ and $ n$ respectively . Set $f(z) = \frac{p(z)}{q(z)}$. show  that

$1)$ $f$ has  removable  singularity at $\infty$  if $n \ge m$

$2)$ $Res [f(z) ; \infty]=0 $ if $n \ge m +2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 1), let 
$f(z) = \frac{a_m z^m + a_{m-1}z^{m-1}+\ldots + a_0}{b_n z^n + b_{n-1}z^{n-1} +\ldots+ b_0}$. Now we divide everything by $z^n$, so

$$f(z)= \frac{\frac{a_m}{z^{n-m}}+ \ldots + a_0 \frac{1}{z^n}}{b_n +\ldots+b_0\frac{1}{z^n}}$$ 
And because $n-m \geq 0$ then taking limit to $\infty$ gives you $\frac{a_m}{b_n}$ if $m=n$ or $0$ if $n > m$.

Then for the residue at $\infty$ use the fact that $Res [f(z) ; \infty]= Res[-\frac{1}{z^2}f(\frac{1}{z});0]$ and proceed the same way as in 1).

Comment: Also for 2)  you can prove that $f'(z)$ is continuous at $\infty$ so inmediatly this tells you the residue must be $0$

Comment: .@Josesquare  thanks u.